# Find the formula of a sequence $a_{1}=1\\a_{2}=2\cos(x)\\a_{n}=a_{n-2}+2\cos((n-1)x), n>2.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is given by $a_{1}=1\\a_{2}=2\cos(x)\\a_{n}=a_{n-2}+2\cos((n-1)x), n>2.$

Am I able to make a simple formula of a sequence element? I found such a solution:

$a_{n}=\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$.

But it doesn't represent the sequences with $n = \pm 1$. Can you help me in finding the formula?

Comment: I believe $n=\pm 1$ in question should be substituted with $\cos x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your candidate to work out, I assume that [induction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) would work to prove it, where you apply ideas from [trigonometric identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Chebyshev_method) in the induction step. At least for $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}\pi$.

One can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow k\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}=(-1)^{k(n+1)}n$. So we can [fill the locus where the expression is undefined](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). Work with the following to get rid of your problems:
$$
a_n(x)=\begin{cases}
(-1)^{k(n+1)}n, &\text{ if }x=k\pi\\
\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}, &\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Also: we do not need to consider $n=-1$, no problem there. For $n=1$ it works out, if we remove the singularities.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment!
But there is still a problem here cause original sequence didn't have any exceptions for $$x=\pi * n$$ in spite of new one. I am really confuses about this trouble.